# Почему первые записи выводятся несколько раз?

Tags: php, mysql

Имеются таблицы:

invites

`id    name       icode
1      Kex        900
2     Anton       343
3     Georg       922`

list

`id     status     offerid
1      accept      900
2      accept      343
3       send       922
4      denied      900
5      denied      900
6       send       900
7       send       900`

Имеется запрос redbean:

```
$query = R::getAll("SELECT * FROM invites, list WHERE invites.icode = list.offerid AND invites.name = 'Kex'");

foreach($query as $row){
   echo $row['status'];
}
```

Вроде все нормально выводится в цикле, но первые 3 строки повторяются по 3 раза, т.е вместо

```
accept
denied
send
send
```

выводится это

```
accept
denied
send
accept
denied
send
accept
denied
send
send
```

и дальше идет все нормально по базе
Пробовал выводить вот так:

```
SELECT l.id, l.status
FROM `list` l
LEFT JOIN invites i ON i.icode = l.offerid
WHERE i.name = 'Kex';
```

но меняется только порядок повтора с 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 на 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать Distinct, спасибо @bask с Тостера.